# Finding element based on two cell values in a table protractor

Tags: selenium, protractor

I am in a weird situation where I have multiple rows with similar values in my rows and I need to select element which has link with text "Protractor" in first cell and text "NewAge" in second cell of same row.

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" class="resultsTable"><tr><td>
        <a href = "Mytitle.aspx">Protractor</a>
        <td>NewAge</td>
        </tr>
    <tr><td>
    <a href = "NewMytitle.aspx"> NewProtractor </a>
        <td>NewAge</td>
        </tr>
    <tr><td>
    <a href = "NewProtTile.aspx">Protractor</a>
        <td>NewAge World</td>
        </tr></table>
```

Now I want my hyperlink element to be picked based on both text values in first and second cell which is 'Protractor' and  'NewAge'

I want to use exact text search instead of containing text as many other rows has similar values
This is the xpath returned by Chrome.

```
//*[@id="PageContent"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/a
```

I tried using xpath to select the link with text as 'Protractor' in first cell and "NewAge" in second cell of same row but not getting an desired results.

```
   element(by.xpath("//tr['Protractor']['NewAge']"))
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: could you clarify how looks like a table please and what you want to find there, thanks

Comment: @Oleksii - Updated question to be more clear.

Comment: You could find an array with rows that has a 'Protractor' text in first cell. and then find a row with 'NewAge' in second cell. I think that kind of decomposition makes it more clear and stable for searching elements in this table. You could wrap it in help function.

Comment: I think there should be some way to select exact element using xpath. Problem with putting them in array is positions for these might change when new rows are added to the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To identify/retrieve the `hyperlink element` based on both text values in first and second cell which is **Protractor** and **NewAge** you can use the following **`xpath`** :

```
//table[@class='resultsTable']//td[text()='NewAge']//preceding::a[text()='Protractor']
```

Comment: I am not able to get desired results. This is how i used.
`by.xpath("//td[text()='7\/38']//preceding::a[text()='2']")`

In my table. 7/38 is last cell and 2 is in first cell. Does it matter if there are more cells with value in between?

Comment: This is the correct Xpath from browser `/html/body/div[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[1]/a`

Comment: Where is `7/38` and `2` in your question? I am sure my Answer would work with the texts `Protractor` and `NewAge`. Please accept the Answer.

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me. I had to use `td[normalize-space(.) = 'New Age']` so that I can ignore spaces. I had `7/38` in my code somewhere which I did not posted. I am still unable to figure out how to ignore slash so if you can help me with that, it will great.

Comment: Just escape the `/` with a additional "\" . So effectively it would be '7\/38'. Let me know the status.

Comment: Without escaping works for me. Thanks. `//table[@class='resultsTable']//td[normalize-space(.) = '7/38']//preceding::a[text()=2]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath to do this.

```
//table[@class='resultsTable]//a[.='Protractor']//following::td[.='NewAge']
```

This starts with the table, finds an A that contains "Protractor", and then finds the next TD that contains "NewAge".

If it were me, I would wrap this in a function that takes in the two parameters to make it reusable. Then you can pass in any two strings, and it will return the value or click the element, whatever you want...

Comment: your xpath will match two elements, it's difficult for program to decide which one is user wanted and the first one can't be always user wanted.

Comment: No, it's not difficult. You use find element (singular) and it returns the correct one. The first one *is* the one he wants each time based on the HTML presented.

Comment: Yes,  only consider the HTML presented currently, the first one is he wanted.

Comment: Actually... my XPath will only return a single element given this HTML. I am using equals and not contains.

Comment: I tried it can match two td,  and from the presented HTML, we can see aftert the a[.='Protractor'],  there are two td which text is NewAge, your xpath matched the two td

Comment: You are right... I realized that earlier when I made the comment the first time and then forgot when I looked at it again a minute ago. What I said the first time is still accurate... OP will always want the first instance so using find element will return the correct instance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162784/discussion-between-yong-and-jeffc).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would handle it. First I would get a list of all rows

```
const rows = browser.element.all(by.tagName('tr'));
```

The I would get a list of rows from that list where the first cell text equals `Protractor`

```
const firstMatches = rows.filter((row) => {
  return row.all(by.tagName('td')).first().getText().then(text => text === 'Protractor');
});
```

Then from this list I would check the second cell equals `NewAge`

```
const secondMatches = firstMatches.filter((row) => {
  return row.all(by.tagName('td')).get(1).getText().then(text => text === 'NewAge');
});
```

If you throw all these together and log the count and text of secondMatches, the number of elements should only be one and the text should be `Protractor NewAge` letting you know you have the right row.

```
const rows = browser.element.all(by.tagName('tr'));
const firstMatches = rows.filter((row) => {
  return row.all(by.tagName('td')).first().getText().then(text => text === 'Protractor');
});

const secondMatches = firstMatches.filter((row) => {
  return row.all(by.tagName('td')).get(1).getText().then(text => text === 'NewAge');
});

secondMatches.count().then(count => {
  console.log(count);
});

secondMatches.first().getText().then(text => {
  console.log(text);    
});
```

Comment: Problem in this approach is my cell positions are not always constant. Protractor can become second row or third row when new data is entered.

Comment: It's only problem in your mind. System will find element each run. What is your concern? Where is you see a hardcoded values?. Wrap above in one helper function and reuse it.

Comment: The code I posted doesn't care what row it is in. It will find all rows that have text in the first cell equal to `Protractor` and then all rows that have `NewAge` in the second cell. The row does not matter. It could be the hundredth row and it would still find it.

Comment: My concern is 'Protractor' is wrapped inside a link tag a so fetching td will not fetch Protractor.

Comment: Yes it will. Did you even try it? I literally copied and pasted your code into an html file. I made absolutely no changes to it and ran this code against it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try below xpath to find the exact row, it can match the only row in my chrome.

```
//table[@class='resultsTable']//tr[td[2][.='NewAge'] and td[1]/a[.='Protractor']]
```

Above xpath is stricted by limited on first and second cell, if you don't care which cell, you can use below xpath:

```
//table[@class='resultsTable']//tr[td[.='NewAge'] and td/a[.='Protractor']]
```

Then find your wanted element inside the matched row. 
For example, you want to click the link inside the fist cell:

```
//table[@class='resultsTable']//tr[td[2][.='NewAge'] and td[1]/a[.='Protractor']]/td[1]/a
```

Or you want to click a link which text is 'Delete' and you don't care it in which cell:

```
//table[@class='resultsTable']//tr[td[2][.='NewAge'] and td[1]/a[.='Protractor']]//a[.='Delete']
```

Comment: It did not worked. In one of my tables, I used this. 
`by.xpath("//table[@class='resultsTable']//tr[td[.='7/38'] and td/a[.='2']]")`
This is how HTML looks like.
`<table><tr><td><a href="MyPage.aspx">2</a></td>
<td>My Title</td>
<td>1/1/2002</td>
<td>7/38</td></tr></table>`
Also, I have 2 table with same class i.e. resultsTable. I am not sure if it matters.

Comment: Please verify the xpath in DevTool manually firstly, rather than verify it by auto script directly.  I trid your xpath on the HTML code, it can match the only one TR.  Which browser you test,  I test on Chrome

Comment: It worked for me however I have a place where I need to search for '7/38'. It is not accepting that. Do i need to use '7\/38' to accept slash?

Comment: Also, it is not accepting text. It is accepting numbers like [.=2] however not accepting text like [.='New Age']

Comment: For text, i am able to do it with td[normalize-space(.) = 'New Age'] as my text had actually spaces in it. However, I am still not able to figure out a way to ignore slash for date format.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out. I was able to ignore slash with preceding forward slash.