# Unable to fetch element value from nested table

Tags: selenium, protractor

I am in a situation where my data is nested inside multiple tables and table has no data elements which can help me identify it. I want to fetch date from this which is `01/09` and there is no class or name associated with any tags below.

```
<table><tbody><tr><td>
<table><tbody><tr><td class='TableHead'></td>
<td>This</td></tr>
<tr><td class='TableHead'></td>
<td>protractor</td></tr>
<tr><td class='TableHead'></td>
<td>01/09</td></tr>
<tr><td class='TableHead'></td>
<td>today</td></tr></tbody></table></tr></td></tbody></table>
```

Can someone please help me get out of this situation and identify element which has date in it?

i tried creating a custom function passing in date as variable and identifying using below xpath but cant find it?

```
FetchDetail(ValueName) {
    return element(by.xpath('//table//tr//td[2][.="'+ValueName+'"]')).isPresent()

}
```

Comment: your function should work, I tried  //table//tr//td[2][.="protractor"] and //table//tr//td[2][.="01/09"] in DevTool, both xpath worked as expect. Try trim the blank on ValueName, like '//table//tr//td[2][.="'+ValueName.trim()+'"]'

Comment: While trying to modify the actual `HTML` you are messing it up every time. I have answered your twisted question [`Finding element based on two cell values in a table protractor`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48155961/finding-element-based-on-two-cell-values-in-a-table-protractor) which didn't fit with your actual case as you twisted the texts. Please Accept that answer if that answered that particular Question. In this Question the **HTML is incorrect** . Within a particular table **`</td>` must occur before `</tr>`**.  So the HTML **</tr></td></tbody></table>** is `incorrect`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a custom function passing in `date` as variable and identify you can use the following `xpath` :

```
FetchDetail(ValueName) {
    return element(by.xpath("//table//table//tr//td[contains(.,'" + ValueName + "')]")).isPresent()

}
```

Answer (score 1):

how about this, it will identify the `td` you are interested in regardless of which table it is in.

```
//td[@class='TableHead'][1]/../td[2]
```

And if that's working, I think following should work too.

```
//td[@class='TableHead'][1]/following-sibling::td
```

Comment: I want to create a custom function so that I can decide which value I want to fetch. For e.g. 01/09 or protractor. Is there any way I can make use it as a function?

Comment: based on what input?